# JBoss deployment credetials via maven

Tags: maven, jboss7.x

gCurrently trying to make deployment of my web-project (EAR packed) into jboss, and met next problem:
settings.xml:

```
<settings>  
    ...  
    <servers>  
        <server>
            <id>default</id>  
            <password>xxx</password>  
            <username>xxx</username>  
        </server>
    </servers> 
    ...
</settings>
```

What do I need to write in jboss-as-maven-plugin configuration in maven pom.xml to make it take credentials from this section? For example, with Tomcat it was < server> parameter. I already tried "server","serverId","id", changing "username" to "name" in settings.xml - no effect.

The reason for this is security measure - lets say i wanna post this project on github etc, but don't want keeping credentials at file. Of-course, as i googled around, I so, how to handle it via command line - therefore, can be handled via IDE. But what in case of many projects etc?... Change everywhere?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the latest plugin, 7.4.Final, in the configuration you just supply the id the server in your settings.xml.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <id>default</id>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What if you're not using the latest plugin you mean?

Comment: Using the settings id is only available in 7.4.Final and up.

Answer (score 0):

In our project we have it defined in maven

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

And then deploy it from teamcity/Jenkins

```
-Djboss-as.hostname=x.x.x.x
-Djboss-as.username=admin
-Djboss-as.password=adminadmin
```